# Bending a user-submitted image with HTML Canvas or Javascript? (or both?)

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing, canvas

Basically, I have [webpage](http://mcstevens.com/previewprivatelabel.aspx) that allows a user to preview what a label what look like on a tin. Achieved through z-indexs by putting a div within a png background image on top of another div where the user submitted image is shown. The image is previewed using the HTML 5 FileViewer API with some Javascript, so no uploading is necessary.

I want to use a [cylindrical tin](http://mcstevens.com/images/products/display/709235ElvisMint.jpg) next, but having a flat image here will just look like crap. Is there a way to bend an image using Javascript or HTML Canvas? I'm fairly new to both, any help is extremely appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: have you looked into the EaselJS part of the CreateJs suite libraries?? I think you could do it with easel

Comment: @RyanWilliams I'm not sure if that can do exactly what I want, but there is some sweet stuff in there. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebGL can texture a cylinder with material.

You could look at three.js

Here's example code (not mine):

http://www.skjapp.com/cylindergeometry-and-cone-example-using-webgl-three-js/#.UfsLN2l8OUk

And here's a demo (not mine):

http://www.skjapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/CylinderExample.html

Comment: Looks like I'll be doing quite a bit of reading, but this is perfect. Thank you!